# Why drush fails with undefined function conf_path() error?

Tags: drush, bootstrapping

Here's a weird one: I've got two nearly identical server setups, both running Drush 5.9. Both have been happy for a while. Went to use one today, and got the error:

`Drush 5.9 does not support Drupal . Use Drush 4 instead.
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function conf_path() in /var/opt/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc, line 786`

The other site runs Drush 5.9 just fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Somehow Drupal version detection failed and drush thinks it's older version. Are you sure you haven't deleted any files it might be using?

Comment: Haven't changed anything. I'm not the only one with access to the server, but I don't think anyone else would, either. Guess I'll see if I can reinstall it.

Comment: Extreme weirdness! It works fine, now. I ran 'drush status', and the error message isn't appearing anymore.

Comment: It's magic. Or [more magic](http://catb.org/jargon/html/magic-story.html). I'm glad it works now, and I doubt if we will ever know the truth.

Comment: Ha ha! Good story!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what command you're trying to run or your file structure, it's difficult to say.

Most commonly this happens when your `drush` has trouble bootstraping your Drupal root, either by corrupted Drupal core files or different loading the wrong files.

In example if you run `drush` inside [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module directory it fails, because it contains `includes/common.inc` file and drush is confused that it's Drupal core version of `common.inc` so it's loading it and expects that `conf_path()` should be defined. The same with `core/includes/common.inc`. Check the [_drush_bootstrap_drupal_site_validate()](http://api.drush.ws/api/drush/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/_drush_bootstrap_drupal_site_validate) function at drush API site.

I believe this has been fixed in the recent drush (see [#60 at GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/60) and original [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1481270)), so please upgrade it to the recent version (see the [instructions](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#installupdate---composer)).

However in some other circumstances the problem is still happening ([#937](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/937)) for some reason.